# Onload Function Not Triggering Function, no console errors

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, onload, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make a JavaScript Announcement which includes a function main() in this case, that is not triggering upon onload function in the body tag I have inserted, , but when I manually trigger this function in Chrome's Console, it works as expected, please help me..
I have Also Used Firebase's Realtime Database for one of the values out of more values that I will use from there..
Code:
[Here is the HTML & JS](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1w1qtpozW9-Ib4PevaENXwWxQs6YrRw50?usp=sharing)

or you can see the Code: 
HTML:

```js
// Firebase Setup
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBz2pk-ec0yn7H25fzLaXI13CmAX4xp1-o",
    authDomain: "learningdb-1.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://learningdb-1-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "learningdb-1",
    storageBucket: "learningdb-1.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "287578856127",
    appId: "1:287578856127:web:0894a806aa5b039bafc40a",
    measurementId: "G-682XPG49J1"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  // Add .child('the reference of the value you want to see like dbRef.on')
  var dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
  let announcements;
  var ann = firebase.database().ref().child('announcements');
  ann.on('value', snap => announcements = snap.val());
// /Firebase Setup and Inialization Complete!
// announcements = true;
function main() {
    if (announcements == true) {
        mainAnnouncement = "AVMC has decided to recontinue the Minecraft Network services           and is expected to be up by 20-25 March. This given date may be                 extended seeing the amount of potential problems in the Network as              of being down for a good time. There will be tests done with some               feature updates and more before going up! ";
        announcementTitle = "Important Notice! ";
        jsPara = document.getElementById('jsId');
        jsPara2 = document.getElementById('jsPara')
        jsPara.innerHTML += `Announcements is set to "${announcements}" <br> 
        <b> [ANNOUNCEMENT BODY] </b> <br>`;
        jsPara2.innerHTML += 
        `<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        <h5>
        <b>${announcementTitle}</b>
        </h5>
        <hr>
        ${mainAnnouncement}
        </div>`
} else if (announcements == false) {
    jsPara = document.getElementById('jsId');
    jsPara.innerHTML = `Announcements is set to "${announcements}"`;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LearningDB-1 | AVMC</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body onload="main()">
<br>
<div class="container">

<h4><u><b>This code triggers an Announcement 
when the value "announcement" is set to "true"</u></b></h4>

<h5 id="jsId"><b> [ANNOUNCEMENT] </b></h5>
<div id="jsPara"></div>
</body>
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Which `<script>` element corresponds to the file containing your `main` function?

Comment: Also, you should be using the `DOMContentLoaded` event instead of `load` (and wire it up using `document.addEventListener` instead of `onload=""`).

Comment: @Dai why not onload?

Comment: @Dai also, its not in an HTML Script tag, you must be seeing the JS I have added in the Code Snippet too

Comment: If your `main` function isn't loaded into the page in a `<script>` element then how do you expect it to be available and even work at all? Running scripts from developer tools is different.

Comment: Because `onload` can be delayed significantly while external resources load, whereas `DOMContentLoaded` is raised much sooner (when the DOM completes loading, but before all external content is loaded).

Comment: @Dai also, the problem isn't that it wasn't called, I checked if the function is called by adding a console.log, it is called, but the code isn't performing, though it does perform when I manually trigger the function in the console, to be specific, the inner if statements isn't getting called, tho as I said, it performs when I manually use Console..